# helm init - error executing access token command

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Running Ubuntu 18.04

kubectl : 1.10

Google Cloud SDK 206.0.0
alpha 2018.06.18
app-engine-python 1.9.70
app-engine-python-extras 1.9.70
beta 2018.06.18
bq 2.0.34
core 2018.06.18
gsutil 4.32

```
helm init 
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /home/jam/snap/helm/common.
Error: error installing: Post https://<ip>/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/kube-system/deployments: error executing access token command "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud config config-helper --format=json": err=fork/exec /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud: no such file or directory output= stderr=
```

I have copy pasted the command and it runs fine

Any help ?

Comment: `/home/jam/snap/helm/common` makes it look like helm is being run from a snap; is that true?

Comment: yes this is true, should I install it differently?

Comment: well, snap is like docker in that I believe its filesystem and _your_ filesystem intersect only in very controlled ways -- otherwise the isolation feature would be null and void. In docker, you can "volume mount" a directory from the host FS into the "guest" FS, so if snap permits such a thing: you'd want to make `/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk` available to the snap's FS -- or, of course, just download (or compile) the `helm` binary like a normal person since it's literally one statically linked go binary

Comment: You are a legend, I did just that as I waited for your reply, works! if you want an accepted answer copy paste your comment above to answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`snap` is like docker in that I believe its filesystem and your filesystem intersect only in very controlled ways -- otherwise the isolation feature would be null and void. In docker, you can "volume mount" a directory from the host FS into the "guest" FS, so if snap permits such a thing: you'd want to make `/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk` available to the snap's FS -- or, of course, just download (or compile) the `helm` binary like a normal person since it's literally one statically linked go binary

Answer (score 1):

In my case, `/snap/google-cloud-sdk/127/bin/gcloud` was called.

I suppose I didn't do it "right", but I just linked my `gcloud` to the file `helm` wanted to run.

```
sudo mkdir -p /snap/google-cloud-sdk/127/bin
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcloud /snap/google-cloud-sdk/127/bin/gcloud
```

After that, `helm` was able to find `gcloud`.

Comment: When you get kube config from gcloud it writes the path to gcloud in the kube config as the auth provider which includes the revision. So once the snap udpates you can loose that revision and break your kube config. This will take a while and be confusing because a gcloud version includes a few revisions.